# SQL Server 2012: Make identity key, primary key also

Tags: sql-server-2012, primary-key, auto-increment

In my table I have a self increment identity key but its not primary. If alter this key to make it primary also, in an existing table will it cause any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No its pretty safe. Use:

alter table  create primary key (column_name)